# WORKING example of buffer overflow in Damn Vulnerable Linux

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, linux-distro

I've had a lot of trouble in getting through buffer overflow exploits from start to finish. I end up with a sigsegv fault instead the intended result. I just downloaded Damn Vulnerable Linux and all I see from reviews about it is 'effective at teaching sql injection..., something, else, buffer overflows'.

However I can not find any tutorials or examples of buffer overflow for DVL. Does anyone know about any working ones?
 I have tried:

http://www.damnvulnerablelinux.org/

which literally doesn't have anything on the site.

I have googled a lot and have only found DVL in reviews.

If someone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Especially if someone has executed a buffer overflow example iv DVL.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2902

This is a working example of a buffer overflow that is from the book, The Art of exploitation' It works I have tried it. Great book by the way

Comment: +1 for [_Hacking - The Art of Exploitation_](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Hacking-Jon-Erickson/9781593271442)